# stack() in R does not include all .tiff files in my directory

Tags: r, modis, time-series, stack, evi

I am trying to perform stack() in R using enhanced vegetation index (EVI) time-series maps but it doesn't include all the .tiff files in my directory. Here's the list of files when I `dir(files.evi)`:

> [1] "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_001.tif" "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_017.tif"
>
> [3] "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_033.tif" "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_049.tif"
>
> [5] "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_065.tif" "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_081.tif"
>
> [7] "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_097.tif" "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_113.tif"
>
> [9] "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_129.tif" "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_145.tif"
>
> [11] "MOD13Q1_EVI_2019_161.tif" "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_009.tif"
>
> [13] "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_025.tif" "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_041.tif"
>
> [15] "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_057.tif" "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_073.tif"
>
> [17] "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_089.tif" "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_105.tif"
>
> [19] "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_121.tif" "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_137.tif"
>
> [21] "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_153.tif" "MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_169.tif"

However, when I do

```
evi <- list.files(files.evi, pattern = glob2rx("*MYD13Q1*.tif$"), full.names = TRUE)
all_evi_st <- stack(evi)
```

it only stack half of the files on my list:

> class      : RasterStack
>
> dimensions : 668, 1105, 738140, 11  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
>
> resolution : 231.6564, 231.6564  (x, y)
>
> extent     : 11251086, 11507066, 1348703, 1503450  (xmin, xmax, ymin,
>   ymax)
>
> crs        : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181
>   +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs
>
> names      : MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_009, MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_025,
>   MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_041, MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_057, MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_073,
>   MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_089, MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_105, MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_121,
>   MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_137, MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_153, MYD13Q1_EVI_2019_169

Can anyone tell me what's happening and what's the workaround? I am new in remote sensing and still shabby with R.

Other info I can give about the time-series images is that they are from MODIS TERRA and AQUA time series derived from the 250 m 16-day composite vegetation index products (MOD13Q1/MYD13Q1).

Comment: Looks like you're loading a different set of files based on the names of the raster layers. What happens when you `print(files.evi)` and `print(evi)`?

Comment: @JepsonNomad, when I do print(files.evi), I get: "~/MODIS/VI_16Days_250m_v6/EVI" and with print(evi), it lists the 11 files in the stack(evi) above.

Comment: So why not just use `stack(dir(files.evi))`? The file list on `evi` is clearly not what you want since it has not only half the layers of dir(files.evi) but also has *different* layers.

Comment: @JepsonNomad that solved it! thanks so much!

Comment: @JepsonNomad It would be good if you could expand your comment just a little and write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear how you generated `files.evi`, but in this case I feel like an easy solution to the problem is using what you know works: If `dir(files.evi)` returns the list of files you want to work with, then use that object to create your raster stack with:

```
d = dir(files.evi)
myraster = raster::stack(d)
```

To expand on the actual problem you have, I'm trying to replicate it on my computer, and I think it somehow relates to file structure. Here, I navigate to a working directory on my computer and then make a path to a subdirectory analagous to what returns when you `print(files.evi)` in the comments. I have a series of .tif files in the subdirectory, with no similarly-names files in the base directory. Trying to use `stack(files.evi)` may because the full names are not generated with this instance of `dir()`, unless you set `full.names = TRUE`. Both your use of `list.files()` and [sn1ks solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/329017/67264) work, but the "solution" that works above for you in the comments (in the absence of `dir(x, full.names = TRUE)` actually only works when I set the working directory to the same subdirectory that contains my images of interest.

```
setwd('PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/')

list.files()
files.evi = "PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/SUBDIRECTORY"
dir(files.evi)

evi <- list.files(files.evi, pattern = glob2rx("*STARTNAME*.tif$"), full.names = TRUE)
evi

evi.b <- list.files(files.evi, pattern = glob2rx("*MIDNAME*.tif$"), full.names = TRUE)
evi.b

myrastera = raster::stack(evi)
myrasterb = raster::stack(evi.b)
myrasterc = raster::stack(dir(files.evi, full.names = TRUE))
myrasterd = raster::stack(dir(files.evi))
```

If line 1 = `setwd("PATH/TO/DIRECTORY")`,`myrasterd = ras...` returns an error because files don't exist in current working directory BUT if line 1 = `setwd("PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/SUBDIRECTORY")`, `myrasterd = ras...` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example

```
 evi <- list.files(files.evi, pattern = glob2rx("*MYD13Q1*.tif$"), full.names = TRUE)
```

in the part after "pattern = ..." you specifically select only the second part of your files, starting with "MYD". the not selected files start with "MOD13Q1", so they are not selected by your code :) You need to change it to:

```
 evi <- list.files(files.evi, pattern = glob2rx("*13Q1*.tif$"), full.names = TRUE)
```

then it should work as desired :)

Comment: you're right, I didn't notice that I have MYD and MOD in my .tiff files.